# Can't call setInterval twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

child element's setInterval stops working when calling the parent element's setInterval. this is how I call setInterval

```
$.fn.__blink = function(color) {
    self = $(this);
    if (self.attr('data-blinker') == undefined) {
        var blinker = setInterval(function() {
            original_color = self.css('background');
            self.css('background', color).delay(300).queue(function(nxt) {
                self.css('background', original_color);
                nxt();
            });
        }, 1000);
        self.attr('data-blinker', blinker);
    }
    return self;
};
```

Elements are in a nav menu where child element is a submenu of a menu item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I can see is you have created `self` abd `original_color` as a global variable, so when you call `__blink` second time the value of `original_color` may get overriden by the second call

```
$.fn.__blink = function (color) {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.attr('data-blinker') == undefined) {
        var blinker = setInterval(function () {
            var original_color = self.css('background');
            self.css('background', color).delay(300).queue(function (nxt) {
                self.css('background', original_color);
                nxt();
            });
        }, 1000);
        self.attr('data-blinker', blinker);
    }
    return self;
};
```

Comment: Will it not create a new instance of those variable?

Comment: not since you have used it without declaring the variables with `var` in the function... the variable will be created in the global scope....